# Is there a C# equivalent of Java's Annotation Processing Tool (apt)?

Tags: c#, java, attributes, annotations, apt

Java's apt tool allows you to execute code at compile time based upon the annotations you place in your code. C# has attributes, which work like Java's annotations, but try as I might I can't seem to find a ready-made tool (ideally an open source one) that provides the same functionality for C# as apt does for Java. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2):

There are some. Such as:

1. Sprint.Net (Open source?) http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html
2. Postsharp (Costs Money) http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net/custom-attributes
3. A tutorial (Open source) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/aopsimplestscenario.aspx

The google search I used was:

https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+aop+attributes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

I have had a look at PostSharp quickly before and it looks very tidy. Sprint.Net is a port from the java Sprint library I believe. There are also numerous code generation libraries out there that you could leverage by reflecting over your assembiles and performing your logic.

Comment: Spring is one of those bloated frameworks which I won't go after if I only need simple AOP.

Comment: AOP (Aspect orientated programming) is not APT (annotation processing). The former being also known as "enhancement" or "weaving" and the later is most often "code generation based on the 'model' of the code being compiled".  They are quite different things - the above links all relate to AOP and not APT.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.

But if you are willing to do your own tool, take a look at [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) for instance. It allows to inspect and modify an assembly. If are using Visual Studio (or similar) you can setup a project so that it executes commands **after** building (i.e. executes your Mono.Cecil based tool).

Answer (score 2):

take a look af fody, a extensible tool for weaving .net assemblies:
https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Comment: Fody uses Mono.Cecil mentioned in another comment.